# What is the meaning of " a far-off quadrant of " in the following sentence?

Tags: meaning

What is the meaning of " a far-off quadrant of " in the following sentence,

> "I gave orders for Alpha Zip to go to a far-off quadrant of the galaxy."

?

Is this area painted in green "a quadrant of the galaxy"?

[image]

Is this area painted in red "a far-off quadrant of the galaxy"?

[image]

Or is this area painted in blue "a far-off quadrant of the galaxy"?

[image]

Comment: You should consult a dictionary first, and then if you are still unclear, ask here.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Far-off mean loads away.

Quadrant means a district; a fourth of an area, especially in Trigonometry, each area shaped by the 'X' and 'Y' axis is called a quadrant.

[image: Four Quadrants in Trigonometry]

Here, in your example, quadrant means area. So, "a far-off quadrant of" means an extremely distant area.

Comment: Does "a  quadrant of the galaxy (circle) " mean the first quadrant of the four areas of the galaxy (circle )? If so, does  "a far-off quadrant of galaxy (circle )" mean the end of the first quadrant of the four areas of the galaxy (circle )?  In the picture you painted, can you paint it ( a far-off quadrant of the galaxy(circle) ) so that I can easily understand where it is?

Comment: Sina//thank you for the picture you painted.  I used a little modification of the picture you painted.

Comment: @user22046 No problem my friend.

Comment: @user22046 Please pay attention, what you have painted doesn't show a far-off quadrant. Far-off quadrant doesn't have anything to do with mathematics. "**Quadrant**" itself means any of those four areas in trigonometry (one of the meanings), but the combination "a far-off quadrant" is completely different. For example, you can consider a galaxy 2 million light years from the Earth, is in a far-off quadrant of the Earth. This is sorta a metaphor.

Comment: By the way the source of the image is Wikimedia. I didn't draw it.

Comment: Is it possible to understand  "It is in a far-off quadrant of the Earth" as "It is in a far-off distance of the Earth"?